# boost::bind and class member function

Tags: c++, boost-bind

Consider following example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void
func(int e, int x) {
    std::cerr << "x is " << x << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "e is " << e << std::endl;
}

struct foo {
    std::vector<int> v;

    void calc(int x) {
        std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
            boost::bind(func, _1, x));
    }

    void func2(int e, int x) {
        std::cerr << "x is " << x << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "e is " << e << std::endl;
    }

};

int
main()
{
    foo f;

    f.v.push_back(1);
    f.v.push_back(2);
    f.v.push_back(3);
    f.v.push_back(4);

    f.calc(1);

    return 0;
}
```

All works fine if I use `func()` function. But in real life application I have to use class member function, i.e. `foo::func2()` in this example. How can I do this with boost::bind ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were really, really close:

```
void calc(int x) {
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
        boost::bind(&foo::func2, this, _1, x));
}
```

EDIT: oops, so was I. heh.

Although, on reflection, there is nothing really wrong with your first working example. You should really favour free functions over member functions where possible - you can see the increased simplicity in your version.

Comment: This is supposed to work with boost::lamba::bind. I didn't use boost::bind much.

Answer (score 1):

While using boost::bind for binding class member functions, the second argument must supply the object context. So your code will work when the second argument is `this`